# Stored Procedure using IF

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, if-statement, stored-procedures

I need some help, I am somewhat still new to SQL. I have a stored procedure that is executed from another application as a smartobject. My code before te changes look like the code in Section 1. I changed the code as per Section 2 so that the stored procedure would first look if the Sales id type was in fact 3 comparing with the membershipnumber in the table memberships from the stored procedure and then do the same in the members table. If the query was 3 with the membership number I wanted it to use the expiry date in the members table and not the section

SELECT @ExpiryDate = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, 0, @CreatedDate)))

That woudl add 364 days to current date

**Section1**

```
USE [HotelStayWorkflow]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[CP_Create_Card]    Script Date: 3/7/2017 2:50:06 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CP_Create_Card] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
 @membershipNumber VARCHAR(MAX),
 @CardId BIGINT = NULL OUTPUT,
 @minsToFirstDeadline int = 2880,--defailt 2 days
 @minsToSecondDeadline int = 5760 --default 4 days



AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CreatedDate DATETIME = GETDATE()
    DECLARE @ExpiryDate DATETIME
    DECLARE @FirstDeadine DATETIME
    DECLARE @SecondDeadline DATETIME

    BEGIN
                SELECT @ExpiryDate = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, 0, @CreatedDate)))
    END


    SELECT @FirstDeadine = DATEADD(MINUTE,@minsToFirstDeadline,GETDATE())
    SELECT @SecondDeadline = DATEADD(MINUTE,@minsToSecondDeadline,GETDATE())
    --Create Card Linked to Membership below
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Cards WHERE MembershipNumber = @membershipNumber AND Enabled = 1)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Cards SET Enabled = 0 WHERE MembershipNumber = @membershipNumber AND Enabled = 1
    END

    INSERT INTO Cards (CardStatusId, MembershipNumber, PrintedDate, Created, Modified, ExpiryDate,FirstDeadline,SecondDeadline, Enabled) 
    VALUES(1, @membershipNumber, @CreatedDate, @CreatedDate, @CreatedDate, @ExpiryDate,@FirstDeadine,@SecondDeadline, 1)    
    SET @CardId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

            -- Return Card Id


END
```

**Section 2**

```
USE [HotelStayWorkflow]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[CP_Create_Card]    Script Date: 3/7/2017 1:08:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CP_Create_Card] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
 @membershipNumber VARCHAR(MAX),
 @CardId BIGINT = NULL OUTPUT,
 @minsToFirstDeadline int = 2880,--defailt 2 days
 @minsToSecondDeadline int = 5760 --default 4 days



AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CreatedDate DATETIME = GETDATE()
    DECLARE @ExpiryDate DATETIME
    DECLARE @FirstDeadine DATETIME
    DECLARE @SecondDeadline DATETIME

    BEGIN
            IF EXIST (FROM Memberships WHERE MembershipNumber = @MembershipNumber AND SalesTypeId = 3 AND Enabled =1)
            AND 
            IF EXIST (FROM Members WHERE MembershipNumber = @MembershipNumber AND Enabled =1)
            SELECT @ExpiryDate = dbo.Members.MembershipExpiry
        OR              

            SELECT @ExpiryDate = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, 0, @CreatedDate)))
    END


    SELECT @FirstDeadine = DATEADD(MINUTE,@minsToFirstDeadline,GETDATE())
    SELECT @SecondDeadline = DATEADD(MINUTE,@minsToSecondDeadline,GETDATE())
    --Create Card Linked to Membership below
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Cards WHERE MembershipNumber = @membershipNumber AND Enabled = 1)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Cards SET Enabled = 0 WHERE MembershipNumber = @membershipNumber AND Enabled = 1
    END

    INSERT INTO Cards (CardStatusId, MembershipNumber, PrintedDate, Created, Modified, ExpiryDate,FirstDeadline,SecondDeadline, Enabled) 
    VALUES(1, @membershipNumber, @CreatedDate, @CreatedDate, @CreatedDate, @ExpiryDate,@FirstDeadine,@SecondDeadline, 1)    
    SET @CardId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

            -- Return Card Id


END
```

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: When I try and run my stored procedure on the section I have added in it gives me errors, not sure if I am usign the command correctly

Comment: Can you add your errors, and what you are trying to achieve to the question please and I will try and help

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CP_Create_Card, Line 30
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CP_Create_Card, Line 32
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure CP_Create_Card, Line 34
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OR'.

Comment: I am trying to tel the store procedure if the value on the membership table for the SalestypeID is 3 it should use the expiry date for the same membership number from the members table if 3 is found in the SalestypeId that is enabled =1. If not it should use the statement  SELECT @ExpiryDate = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, 0, @CreatedDate)))

Comment: So it would be that when the first section is Tue on the value 3, it would then use the membership number from that table and look the membership number up on the Members.dbo and use that expiry date

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, as you have not included all columns it is difficult to complete this answer.

```
   SELECT @ExpiryDate = M.MembershipExpiry From Memberships M WHERE M.MembershipNumber = @MembershipNumber AND M.SalesTypeId = 3 AND M.[Enabled] =1

        IF @ExpiryDate IS NULL
        BEGIN
           SELECT @ExpiryDate = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, 0, @CreatedDate)))
        end
```

Comment: Hi I tried the code given but it was pulling the columns from the wrong tables. I adjusted the code but I am getting and erro on the second 'AND and table name' only if the M.SalesTypeId = 3 AND M.[Enabled] =1 must the expiry be used

Answer (score 0):

changed code to

BEGIN
    SELECT @ExpiryDate = MembershipExpiry From Members M WHERE M.MembershipNumber = @MembershipNumber
    Memberships MS WHERE M.MembershipNumber = @MembershipNumber AND SalesTypeId = 3 AND MS.[Enabled] =1

```
    IF @ExpiryDate IS NULL
            SELECT @ExpiryDate = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, 0, @CreatedDate)))
END
```